# How to print the probability of each bigram in table format

Tags: python

The exact format I want to print is like this:

```
Bigram                                    MLE Prob       Bigram Prob
"interesting news"                        0.000xxxx        0.000xxx
"interesting show"                        0.000xxxx        0.000x
..(any bigram word set in the text)...
....
...
```

and below is my code.

```
from __future__import division
import re
import string
f = open("C:\Python27\text.txt", "rU")
rawtext = f.read()
bigrams = {}
words_punct = rawtext.split()
words = [ w. strip(string.punctuation).lower() for w in words_punct ]
words = ["START"] + words + ["END"]
for index, word in enumerate(words):
    if index < len(words) - 1:
    w1 = words[index] 
    w2 = words[index + 1]
    bigram = (w1, w2)
    if bigram in bigrams:
        bigrams[ bigram ] = bigrams[ bigram ] + 1
    else:
        bigrams[ bigram ] = 1

sorted_bigrams = sorted(bigrams.items(), key = lambda pair:pair[1], reverse = True)
for bigram, count in sorted_bigrams:
    Bi_Prob = count / sum(list(bigrams.values()))
    print Bi_Prob
```

This gives me the Bi_Prob of each bigram. ( i.e. 0.000xxx, 0.0000xxx, 0.0000x....)
I don't know well about Python, so I've got lots of help here, and anyway
I can make the variable MLE Prob soon.. but I'm having hard time printing that result in table format..I tried the tabulate module, like below.

```
from tabulate import tabulate
for bigram in sorted_bigrams:
    print tabulate([[bigram]], headers = ['Bigram']
```

something like this...but it doesn't work...that means, using tabulate module, I can get the exact printing result that I uttered previously but it contains only one data. I want some looping result...every bigram, and its probability should be inserted in the table form...

help me and give me some other advices too..

p.s. I didn't use nltk, here. But I installed it anyway. but don't know how to use it. I heard nltk can ease my life...

Comment: You might check out formatting help - your desired format seems borked.

Comment: I edited to the code format. the first paragraph.

Comment: Much better. Some advice - you really only have one problem here, and that's *displaying* the data. So you could remove the parts of your question that have to deal with generating the data, and just create an example data set, that looks a bit like whatever the output of `print(bigrams)` is. That would produce a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)